# Reportlab: fix header so it can't go upwards?

Tags: python, pdf, e-commerce, reportlab

I'm trying to create an invoice generator with python and ReportLab, i use canvas to make my pdf-file (table.wrapOn and table.drawOn methods). Now, when I add an item, the header of the table goes upwards. I want the header to be fixed and every time i add an item, the table goes further down.

```
import json
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

with open('json/data.json') as json_file:
    products = json.load(json_file)


eindtotaal = 0

data = [
    ['Aantal', 'Productnaam', 'BTW', 'Prijs', 'Totaal (incl. BTW)']
]

for item in products:
    aantal = item['Aantal']
    omschrijving = item['Omschrijving']
    prijs = item['Prijs']
    totaal = '{:.2f}'.format(aantal*prijs)

    eindtotaal += aantal*prijs

    lijst = [aantal, omschrijving, item['BTW'], prijs, totaal]

    data.append(lijst)


data.append(['', '', '', '', eindtotaal])



fileName = 'invoice.pdf'

from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4

pdf = canvas.Canvas(fileName)

from reportlab.platypus import Table
table = Table(data)

from reportlab.platypus import TableStyle
from reportlab.lib import colors

style = TableStyle([
    ('TEXTCOLOR',(0,0),(-1,-1),colors.black),

    ('ALIGN',(0,0),(-1,-1),'CENTER'),
    ('ALIGN', (4,0), (4,-1), 'RIGHT'),
    ('ALIGN', (1,0), (1,-1), 'LEFT'),

    ('FONTNAME', (0,0), (-1,0), 'Courier-Bold'),
    ('FONTSIZE', (0,0), (-1,0), 12),

    ('FONTNAME', (4,-1), (4,-1), 'Courier-Bold'),
    ('FONTSIZE', (4,-1), (4,-1), 14),


    ('BOTTOMPADDING', (0,0), (-1,0), 12),

    ('BOTTOMPADDING', (0,1), (-1,-1), 9),
    ('TOPPADDING', (0,1), (-1,-1), 9)
])

table.setStyle(style)

ts = TableStyle(
    [
    ('LINEBELOW', (0,0), (-1,0), 2, colors.black),
    ('LINEBELOW', (0,1), (-1,-2), 0.5, colors.grey)
    ]
)
table.setStyle(ts)


table.wrapOn(pdf, 0, 0)
table.drawOn(pdf, 100, 500)

pdf.showPage()

pdf.save()
```

My json data:

```
[
    {
        "Prijs": 249.99,
        "Aantal": 5,
        "Omschrijving": "Article 1",
        "BTW": "21%"
    },

    {
        "Prijs": 21.95,
        "Aantal": 2,
        "Omschrijving": "Article 2",
        "BTW": "21%"
    }

]
```

So now when i add an item to my json array, the header of the table goes up.

Sorry for the dutch terms.